# After click disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have method that after click print my document. I want after click disable my button. I use         `document.getElementsByName("btnGreenCard")[0].disabled = true;` but is not working. Button isn`t disabled.

```
    PerformLongRunningOperation: function (path, operationId, messageSetterMethod) {
    messageSetterMethod();

    $.blockUI.defaultAction();
    var w = window.open(path + "?id=" + operationId, '_self', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');

    $.get('/Data/WaitToComplete/' + operationId + '?unique=' + this.GenerateGuid(), function (data) {

        $.unblockUI();
    });
    document.getElementsByName("btnGreenCard")[0].disabled = true;

    return false;
}
```

My button:

```
  <button type='submit' name="btnGreenCard" id="btnGreenCard" value="GreenCard" onclick="javascript:return Helpers.PerformLongRunningOperation('/PrintPolicy/GreenCard/','<%=Model.PolicyForPrintGuid%>',$.blockUI.setPdfMessage);">
                        Print</button>
```

Any help or sugestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setAttribute`:

`document.getElementsByName("btnGreenCard")[0].setAttribute("disabled", true)`

Comment: Works is blocked. I still have a question how to make the button grayed out?

Comment: Since it might have some styling already, you need to add custom css to the `#btnGreenCard` selector

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jquery you can use this snippet

```
$('button[name="btnGreenCard"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

hope that will help you happy coding